# ASP.NET with Google authentication throws error : The oauth state was missing or invalid

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-oauth-.net-client

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BltfN.png)
I`m developing an googleOAuth2.0 for authorization at ASP.net Core Web Api v7.0. I created a web app in console.cloud.google.com and got the app credentials. I followed to this instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I tried this method and it didn`t create an google icon auth and didnt redirect me when i click at button to sign in. Maybe it need to create a controller.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
});

services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
}); 

builder.Services.RegisterCoreConfiguration(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.RegisterCoreDependencies();
```

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

    <strong style="text-align:center">Home page of future Tinder Clone Web APP :)</strong>

    <a href="/signin-google">Sign In</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are missing DefaultScheme and DefaultChallengeScheme.  The link that you posted says that the project template used in this tutorial ensures Identity is configured. I don't see AddIndentity() in your code. Try this:
                                                    
                                                    
services.AddAuthentication(options=>options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;).AddCookie().AddGoogle(...)

Comment: thanks for help! I do this correct?

 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
});
if that what you mean, i run it and problem still the same.
Can it be problem with project type?